# Getting message -> Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg lib in my library.For that purpose,i have successfully compiled it.But when i try to execute any command,i am getting this message:

```
Invalid data found when processing input.
```

I don't know whats the reason behind it.This is the code:

```
public class Videokit extends Activity {
    String FilePath;
    String OutPut;
    Context mycontext;
    Videokit vk ;
    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("videokit");
    }

    public native void run(String[] args);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FilePath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/output.3gp";
        try {
            ffmpegrun();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String ffmpegrun() throws IOException
    {
        boolean success=false;
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/image-%3d.jpeg");
        File file = new File(FilePath);
        System.out.println("filepath exists at:"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
//              Toast.makeText(mycontext,"outfile.mp4 exists at"+folder.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             OutPut = folder.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        System.out.println("outfile.flv exists at:"+folder.getAbsolutePath());
        run(new String[]{
                "ffmpeg",
                "-i",
                FilePath,
                "-r 1", 
                 "-f",
                 "image2",
                 "image-%3d.jpeg"
        }); 
        return OutPut;
    }
}
```

This is the log :

```
10-07 17:00:03.707: D/dalvikvm(8760): Trying to load lib /data/data/uk.co.halfninja.videokit/lib/libvideokit.so 0x44e8c958
10-07 17:00:03.837: D/dalvikvm(8760): Added shared lib /data/data/uk.co.halfninja.videokit/lib/libvideokit.so 0x44e8c958
10-07 17:00:03.837: I/Videokit(8760): Loading native library compiled at 13:52:27 Oct  7 2012
10-07 17:00:03.917: I/System.out(8760): filepath exists at:/sdcard/output.3gp
10-07 17:00:03.917: I/System.out(8760): outfile.flv exists at:/sdcard/image-%3d.jpeg
10-07 17:00:03.917: D/dalvikvm(8760): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'run' (wrong CL)
10-07 17:00:03.917: D/dalvikvm(8760): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so' for 'run' (wrong CL)
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/dalvikvm(8760): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libexif.so' for 'run' (wrong CL)
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/Videokit(8760): run() called
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/Videokit(8760): run passing off to main()
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/Videokit(8760): main(): registering all modules
10-07 17:00:03.938: D/Videokit(8760): main(): registered everything
10-07 17:00:03.938: D/Videokit(8760): main(): initting opts
10-07 17:00:03.968: D/Videokit(8760): main(): initted opts.
10-07 17:00:03.968: E/Videokit(8760): ffmpeg version N-30996-gf925b24, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
10-07 17:00:03.979: E/Videokit(8760):   built on Oct  7 2012 13:52:32 with gcc 4.4.3
10-07 17:00:03.979: E/Videokit(8760):   configuration: --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm5te --enable-armv5te --target-os=linux --disable-stripping --prefix=../output --disable-neon --enable-version3 --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack --cc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --ld=arm-linux-androideabi-ld --extra-cflags='-fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated' --disable-everything --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-libx264 --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-protocol=file --enable-hwaccels --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-filter=buffer --enable-filter=buffersink --disable-demuxer=v4l --disable-demuxer=v4l2 --disable-indev=v4l --disable-indev=v4l2 --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -Ivideokit' --extra-ldflags=-L../x264
10-07 17:00:03.987: D/Videokit(8760): main(): parsing options
10-07 17:00:03.987: D/Videokit(8760): parse_options has 7 options to parse
10-07 17:00:04.050: E/Videokit(8760): /sdcard/output.3gp: Invalid data found when processing input
10-07 17:00:04.050: E/Videokit(8760): ffmpeg_exit(1) called!
```

Please help me.I am clueless about this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is the input file that's being processed? Is it playable on it's own? Lastly, are you specifying the input type (ex: -f h264)?

Comment: The input file is one mp4 video and sir i am not specifying the input type.Please tell me how to specify it.

Comment: May try this: ffmpeg -f <format> -i <input> ... additional commands. Maybe this will help. In your case I believe the format should be mp4 I believe. It's been a while ;-)

Comment: Is the input file valid? Playable otherwise through gallery?

Comment: Yes sir,the input file is otherwise playable.

Comment: I was getting the same message and I found that while I could play the video it had somehow become corrupted.  I copied the same file into the directory, overwriting the corrupt one, and then the command worked.

Comment: I would remove `--disable-everything --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-libx264 --enable-decoder=rawvideo` for compiling FFmpeg, in order to enable all stuff. This is how it worked for me.